# Payment system migration

Tags: c#

[GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/paydemo)

There need to be a software design supporting gradual migration from one payment system (E-xact) to another (Stripe). Credit cards data are stored outside, so I would like to use both systems in parallel for a while to do not make all users to re-enter credit card data.

Here is what I have at the moment in the domain core:

```
public interface IMainPaymentAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
}

public interface IPaymentAdapter : IPaymentService
{
}

public interface IPaymentGateway : IPaymentService
{
}

public interface IPaymentService
{
    Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card);
    Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount);
}
```

The idea is that `IPaymentService` defines API shape, `IPaymentAdaptor` is about to be implemented for each payment system in use, `IPaymentGateway` dispatches calls to the right adaptor based on a `BillingId` and is supposed to be injected into the consuming code:

```
public abstract class BillingId
{
    public static BillingId Parse(string text)
    {
        var parts = text.Split('/');
        return (BillingId)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(BillingId<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(parts[0])),
            parts[1]);
    }

    protected BillingId(string value) => Value = value;
    public string Value { get; }
    public abstract Type Adapter { get; }
    public override string ToString() => 
        $"{Adapter.AssemblyQualifiedName}/{Value}";
}

public class BillingId<TAdapter> : BillingId 
    where TAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
    public BillingId(string value) : base(value) { }
    public override Type Adapter => typeof(TAdapter);
}
```

My gateway looks like this – note that card registration call is always dispatched to the current `IMainPaymentAdaptor` implementation, while everything else goes to the adaptor that provided the billing id originally:

```
[Service]
public class PaymentGateway : IPaymentGateway
{
    public PaymentGateway(IServiceProvider provider) => Provider = provider;
    IServiceProvider Provider { get; }

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        await Adapter().RegisterAsync(card);

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Adapter(id).ChargeAsync(id, amount); 

    IPaymentAdapter Adapter() => Adapter(typeof(IMainPaymentAdapter));
    IPaymentAdapter Adapter(BillingId id) => Adapter(id.Adapter);
    IPaymentAdapter Adapter(Type type) => 
        (IPaymentAdapter)Provider.GetService(type);
}
```

Here is what I have in a Stripe adapter assembly:

```
public interface IStripeAdapter : IMainPaymentAdapter
{
}

[Service]
public class StripeAdapter : IStripeAdapter
{
    StripeClient Client { get; } = new StripeClient();

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        new BillingId<IStripeAdapter>(await Client.RegisterAsync(card));

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Client.Charge(id.Value, amount);
}
```

Note that `E-xact` adapter (a decommissioning one) should be based on `IPaymentAdaptor`, not the `IMainPaymentAdapter`:

```
public interface IEXactAdapter : IPaymentAdapter
{
}
```

What would you say about this design approach? Does it look clean enough?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simplified version, thanks to this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/402712/126611).

```
public interface IMainPaymentProvider : IPaymentProvider
{
}

public interface IPaymentProvider : IPaymentService
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IPaymentGateway : IPaymentService
{
}

public interface IPaymentService
{
    Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card);
    Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount);
}
```

Where:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BillingIdTypeConverter))]
[JsonConverter(typeof(BillingIdJsonConverter))]
public class BillingId
{
    public static BillingId Parse(string text) =>
        IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ? null :
        text.Split(new[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) is string[] p && p.Length == 2
            ? new BillingId(p[0], p[1]) 
            : throw new FormatException();

    public BillingId(string provider, string value) => 
        (Provider, Value) = (provider, value);

    public string Provider { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public override string ToString() => 
        $"{Provider}:{Value}";
}
```

So payment gateway looks like:

```
[Service]
public class PaymentGateway : IPaymentGateway
{
    public PaymentGateway(IMainPaymentProvider mainProvider, params IPaymentProvider[] providers) => 
        (MainProvider, Providers) = 
        (mainProvider, providers.ToDictionary(p => p.Name));

    IPaymentProvider MainProvider { get; }
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IPaymentProvider> Providers { get; }

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        await MainProvider.RegisterAsync(card);

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Providers[id.Provider].ChargeAsync(id, amount); 
}
```

And a sample provider could be:

```
public interface IStripeProvider : IMainPaymentProvider
{
}

[Service]
public class StripeProvider : IStripeProvider
{
    StripeClient Client { get; } = new StripeClient();

    public string Name => "Stripe";

    public async Task<BillingId> RegisterAsync(CreditCard card) =>
        new BillingId(Name, await Client.RegisterAsync(card));

    public async Task ChargeAsync(BillingId id, decimal amount) =>
        await Client.Charge(id.Value, amount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this code.  It's a good idea to summarise which changes you made, and why - a self-answer ought to review the code, just like any other answer.